# Dynamically constructing objects in an area that can be discarded all at once

Tags: c++, caching

For building a cache-like data structure, I would like to do the following:

I would like to have a `class Cache` building and managing some data structure in some area of memory of a predefined size.

For building the data structure, the `Cache` class should be able to use standard classes like, e.g., `vector`. Now all objects dynamically allocated by the `Cache` class (directly or indirectly) should go into the predefined area in memory, which I would like to be able to discard all at once (i.e. without destructing each individual object) by simply zeroing it (or forgetting about it). I know that this is against the standard.

I thought of the following approach:

```
alter_operator_new_to_allocate_everything_within_my_cache_area ();
cache.cacheMyObjects (...);
alter_operator_new_into_normal_behaviour ();
```

Questions:

- Is such an approach, or a solution to a similar problem, described
  anywhere?
- Will that work?
- Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Of course, I could as well try to write the cache class from scratch such that is uses only POD data structures, but that would mean reinventing the wheel in many cases.

I only need a solution that works for VS2013/2015 and Windows.

Comment: use placement new and memory pool.

Comment: You want to "delete" the contained objects *without* calling their destructors?  That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: In addition to what @Jichao said, you'd need custom allocators for classes such as `std::vector`. Probably not a good idea however.

Comment: Yep, placement `new` is for exactly this purpose (among others).

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth Why? The only problem are objects that refer to something I cannot control when they are constructed (i.e. to something outside my predefined memory area).

Comment: Well, yes, pretty much any class that has a defined destructor, or has member variables which in turn have destructors (and so on).

Comment: But what do I do if the classes I want to use themselves do not use placement new?

Comment: @JohnB That's why you need custom allocators. You have to implement an allocator that uses placement new for those classes.

Comment: Example: Suppose I want to cache a ton of compiled boost::regexe's. If I know that during construction of these regexes every dynamically allocated object was allocated between memory adress a and memory address b, then I can simply re-use this memory space if I do not need the regexes anymore.

Comment: The problem is that if you construct a type that allocates memory itself (such as std::string), then that type's memory won't be deallocated when you simply overwrite, since its destructor won't be called. You will have memory leaks for every single instance of that type whenever you allocate. Like others have said, you do need a memory pool for what you want. You could optimize it by having your memory pool not call the destructor of POD types, since those can be safely overwritten and calling the destructor of non-POD types.

Comment: But how do I ensure that *all* allocations go to the memory pool while the cache is being filled?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are trying to solve can be done with a custom allocator.

You can preallocate the large chunk of contiguous memory you will need for the cache. You can then define a custom allocator object to always allocate from that block of memory. Then pass that allocator object to std::vector or any other data structure [see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/, second template parameter].

Your allocator class must implement the members declared in allocator_traits: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits

Example:

```
class my_allocator {
   void* memory_block;
   my_allocator() { memory_block = malloc( ... ); }
   ~my_allocator() { free(memory_block); }
   void* allocate(..) { ..assign from memory_block.. } 
};

class Cache {
    my_allocator my_alloc;
    std::vector< int, my_alloc > my_vector;

    ..other data..
};
```

Henceforth, your vector will always assign from the memory_block. If you do this with all your data structures in Cache, it will always use the same contiguous memory.
(I've not compiled the code, so there might be somewhat different semantics)

Comment: Problem: If I have a `std::vector< boost::regex, my_alloc > my_vector;`, then the memory dynamically allocated by the regexes will not live within the predefined memory area, so I cannot discard them without destructing them.

Comment: For this approach to work, the classes you use must allow for custom allocators (I'm not sure if boost does this here). You could store it as a basic_string perhaps: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string